# SQL inner select with reference to calculated value

Tags: sql-server-2012

This almost works…

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ObjectThumb.dotID, dbo.ObjectThumb.doID, 
    dbo.ObjectThumb.dotWidth, dbo.ObjectThumb.dotHeight, 
    dbo.Object.doWidth, dbo.Object.doHeight, 
    (CAST(dotWidth AS FLOAT) / CAST(doWidth AS FLOAT)) AS 'widthRatio', 
    (CAST(dotHeight AS FLOAT) / CAST(doHeight AS FLOAT)) AS 'heightRatio', 
    (SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES (widthRatio), (heightRatio)) AS value(v)) AS MaxRatio 
FROM 
   dbo.ObjectThumb 
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Object ON Object.doID = ObjectThumb.doID
```

Server returns an error:

> Invalid column name widthRatio
>   Invalid column name heightRatio

Those columns are calculated in the outer select. If I reference two non-calculated columns (doID & dotID, for example), my query runs.

I think I have the syntax of the inner select screwed up. This to be run on SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.2550).

I can't be far from the right syntax for that inner column. For instance, if I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (1,2), (5,3), (1,4)) AS tableOfValues (columnName1, ColumnName2)
```

I get

```
1 2
5 3
1 4
```

I would appreciate help with the syntax to reference the calculated columns in the outer select. And if you could tell me the correct English to indicate inner-select, outer-select and calculated columns, that would be a bonus!

Comment: Can you please clarify the intended result of `MaxRatio`? It seems like it currently is designed to select a single ratio that is the largest from a column containing values from both `widthRatio` and `heightRatio`. On the other hand your working example seems to want to select two separate values. What should be the result of `MaxRatio` for each row?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I need the larger of the two. Thanks !

Comment: I need the larger of the two (widthRatio / heightRatio). The working sample was demonstrating viability of the inner-select, but the two values there are not part of my intended result. Thanks !

Comment: When you say "the larger of the two" do you mean per ID or overall?

Comment: The larger of the two for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing here to understand is that your logic is not going to work. You cannot select a value in your main query, in this case `widthRatio` and `heightRatio` from a sub-select or inline query as it is out of the scope of that query. Knowing that what you will want to do is instead create an inline query that you will join to your main query.

Your inline query should look something like this

```
Select ObjectThumb.doID As 'LinkID',
    (CAST(dotWidth AS FLOAT) / CAST(doWidth AS FLOAT)) AS 'Ratio'
From ObjectThumb 
    INNER JOIN Object ON Object.doID = ObjectThumb.doID

Union

Select ObjectThumb.doID,
    (CAST(dotHeight AS FLOAT) / CAST(doHeight AS FLOAT))
From ObjectThumb 
    INNER JOIN Object ON Object.doID = ObjectThumb.doID
```

You can then Join your inline query like this

```
SELECT ObjectThumb.dotID, 
       ObjectThumb.doID, 
       ObjectThumb.dotWidth, 
       ObjectThumb.dotHeight, 
       Object.doWidth, 
       Object.doHeight, 
       (CAST(dotWidth AS FLOAT) / CAST(doWidth AS FLOAT)) AS 'widthRatio', 
       (CAST(dotHeight AS FLOAT) / CAST(doHeight AS FLOAT)) AS 'heightRatio',
       Max(AllRatioTable.Ratio) As MaxRatio
From ObjectThumb 
    INNER JOIN Object ON Object.doID = ObjectThumb.doID
    Inner Join (Select ObjectThumb.doID As 'LinkID',
                    (CAST(dotWidth AS FLOAT) / CAST(doWidth AS FLOAT)) AS 'Ratio'
                From ObjectThumb 
                    INNER JOIN Object ON Object.doID = ObjectThumb.doID

                Union

                Select ObjectThumb.doID,
                    (CAST(dotHeight AS FLOAT) / CAST(doHeight AS FLOAT))
                From ObjectThumb 
                    INNER JOIN Object ON Object.doID = ObjectThumb.doID
                ) As AllRatioTable
        On ObjectThumb.doID = AllRatioTable.LinkID
Group by ObjectThumb.dotID, 
         ObjectThumb.doID, 
         ObjectThumb.dotWidth, 
         ObjectThumb.dotHeight, 
         Object.doWidth, 
         Object.doHeight
```

Also on the topic of what to call your sub-select, see here:

http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/81062/what-is-different-between-inline-query-subquery-corelated-query.html

Comment: Clearly, you put a lot of effort into this, & it is greatly appreciated